# How do I convert an array object into a two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

Here is a Array list.

```
const list = [
  {
    id: 5844,
    option: 'fruit'
    children: ['apple', 'banana', 'pear']
  },
  {
   id: 5845,
   option: 'vegetables'
   children: ['tomato', 'potato', 'spinach']
  }
]
```

I want to get a new array like this

apple of fruit's children is index 0

tomato of vegetables's children is index = 0

so they are match

```
[['apple', 'tomato'], ['banana', 'potato'], ['pear', 'spinach']]
```

Comment: Can you add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Also, are you always only going to have two objects whose children you iterate over?

Comment: no, it may be many objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this solution it doesn't matter how many objects are in the array. You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the children in the first object and use it's length to return a [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) of the children elements.

```js
const list=[{id:5844,option:"fruit",children:["apple","banana","pear"]},{id:5845,option:"vegetables",children:["tomato","potato","spinach"]},{id:5846,option:"buildings",children:["church","warehouse","skyscraper"]}];

function getNewData(list) {

  // `map` over the children in the first object
  // using its index to return a new flattened array
  // of all array object children
  return list[0].children.map((_, i) => {
    return list.flatMap(obj => obj.children[i]);
  });
}

console.log(getNewData(list));
```

Comment: what a beautiful code! Thank you !
But i'm not very understand this code, so i am seeing mdn

Comment: `map` returns an array by looping over and array. All the code does is use the first object as a guide to return a new array of items from all of the children array which it then flattens. You could easily have used `forEach` or a nested loop but I this approach. Happy coding!

Comment: I understand , that's so clean code.

Comment: PS if you log bits of the code to the browser console you see see how it works. It's a useful debugging tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can try this piece of code

```
const list = [
  {
    id: 5844,
    option: 'fruit',
    children: ['apple', 'banana', 'pear']
  },
  {
    id: 5845,
    option: 'vegetables',
    children: ['tomato', 'potato', 'spinach']
  }
]

var ans = []
list.forEach(item => {

  item.children.forEach((child, index) => {

    if (!ans[index]) {
      ans[index] = []
      ans[index].push(child)
    } else {

      ans[index].push(child)
    }
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your children have same length. We can use 2 loop to group the element of children.

First loop to iterate the element of children.

Second loop to iterate the element of list.

Here is simple code to solve your case.

```
var listSize = list.length;
var childSize = list[0].children.length;
var expectedArrs = [];
for(var i=0;i<childSize;i++){
  var groupByChild = [];
  for(var j=0;j<listSize;j++){
     groupByChild.push(list[j].children[i]);
  }
  expectedArrs.push(groupByChild);
}
console.log(expectedArrs);
```

The result of console:

```
[["apple", "tomato"], ["banana", "potato"], ["pear", "spinach"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved such that:

```
const result = []
for(let i = 0; i< List[0].children; i++){
const result1 = []
result1.push(list[0].children[i] )
result1.push(list[1].children[i])

result.push(result1)
}
```

Comment: But, it not only two object